# Find and replace a substring after a word in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string which has email id as plain text in it ,I want to replace the email id in the string with hashed value eg.

```
var str ="Token=wUFvvW4pLDjO2Kh9BkF6ShNXMpWCAH84RQrF2GMSMvkT9ji1HWER/hPcDzQVZ+eqfBnzltOP0+NJTa/x6+XrKcSR090Jka8Awdj13CiSiD5OXwFbCHzYX0nzwkbWJ3m7zvyvjIWJJZ7L53YRHckAeTzA39UWR53/s8PHyL7hUu8=&ssoComplete=true&userId=testmail5@gmail.com|flca+&siteID=OXchfjbB"
```

Before storing the above string I want to hash only **`testmail5@gmail.com`** which is after `userId=`. Hence need suggestions to achieve the same.

Comment: isn't `userId` value is `testmail5@gmail.com|flca+`?

Comment: no testmail5@gmail.com is the value for userId appended with and addition value but even taking testmail5@gmail.com|flca as userId is lso fine

Answer (score 0):

Using `split` twice

```js
var str="Token=wUFvvW4pLDjO2Kh9BkF6ShNXMpWCAH84RQrF2GMSMvkT9ji1HWER/hPcDzQVZ+eqfBnzltOP0+NJTa/x6+XrKcSR090Jka8Awdj13CiSiD5OXwFbCHzYX0nzwkbWJ3m7zvyvjIWJJZ7L53YRHckAeTzA39UWR53/s8PHyL7hUu8=&ssoComplete=true&userId=testmail5@gmail.com|flca+&siteID=OXchfjbB" 
console.log(str.split('userId=')[1].split('|')[0])
```

Comment: And you can add this too `str.replace(str.split('userId=')[1].split('|')[0],"some hash");` To replace it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
str.match(/\userId=(.*?)\|/)[1]
```

Regex are better to do stuff like that

Comment: Thanks for the regex,this is working fine but I came across a strange situation where we don't have | in the string then this code is not working properly.Appreciate if share regex to get the emailid out of that string like var pgUrl =  "Token=wUFvvW4pLDjO2Kh9BkF6ShNXMpWCAH84RQrF2GMSMvkT9ji1HWER/hPcDzQVZ+eqfBnzltOP0+NJTa/x6+XrKcSR090Jka8Awdj13CiSiD5OXwFbCHzYX0nzwkbWJ3m7zvyvjIWJJZ7L53YRHckAeTzA39UWR53/s8PHyL7hUu8=&ssoComplete=true&userId=testmail5@gmail.com+&siteID=OXchfjbB";

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty way by using `URL` API in JS.

```js
var data = "Token=wUFvvW4pLDjO2Kh9BkF6ShNXMpWCAH84RQrF2GMSMvkT9ji1HWER/hPcDzQVZ+eqfBnzltOP0+NJTa/x6+XrKcSR090Jka8Awdj13CiSiD5OXwFbCHzYX0nzwkbWJ3m7zvyvjIWJJZ7L53YRHckAeTzA39UWR53/s8PHyL7hUu8=&ssoComplete=true&userId=testmail5@gmail.com|flca+&siteID=OXchfjbB";
var some_hash = "myHashValue";

var data_url = new URL("http://localhost/?"+data);  // dirty part
var new_data = data.replace(data_url.searchParams.get("userId").split('|')[0], some_hash);
console.log(new_data);
```